# PIVOT does not recognise column enclosed in quotes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Sample SQL below - basically if we run this query with "category" instead defined as category (no quotes) it works fine. But the below fails with `SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 14 invalid identifier '"category"'.` Any ideas?

```
create or replace table monthly_sales(empid int, amount int, month text, "category" text)
    as select * from values
    (1, 10000, 'JAN', 'aaa'),
    (1, 400, 'JAN', 'xxx'),
    (2, 4500, 'JAN', 'aaa'),
    (2, 35000, 'JAN', 'aaa'),
    (1, 5000, 'FEB', 'bbb'),
    (1, 3000, 'FEB', 'bbb'),
    (2, 200, 'FEB', 'bbb'),
    (2, 90500, 'FEB', 'aaa'),
    (1, 6000, 'MAR', 'zzz'),
    (1, 5000, 'MAR', 'aaa'),
    (2, 2500, 'MAR', 'ttt'),
    (2, 9500, 'MAR', 'aaa'),
    (1, 8000, 'APR', 'iii'),
    (1, 10000, 'APR', 'iii'),
    (2, 800, 'APR', 'aaa'),
    (2, 4500, 'APR', 'zzz');

select empid, "category", "'JAN'", "'FEB'", "'MAR'", "'APR'"
  from monthly_sales
    pivot(sum(amount) for month in ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR'))
      as p
  order by empid;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your code work if you execute this in your session:

```
alter session set quoted_identifiers_ignore_case = true;
```

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#quoted-identifiers-ignore-case

Edit: If you don't want to do that you have to enclose "category" in your select query with single quotes:

```
select empid, '"category"', "'JAN'", "'FEB'", "'MAR'", "'APR'"
  from monthly_sales
    pivot(sum(amount) for month in ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR'))
      as p
  order by empid;
```

Comment: Thanks. Annoyingly I did try the single quotes thing but I must have had a typo. Cheers!